# Exportar conteúdo de tabela pra um arquivo de Excel

Tags: php, javascript, microsoft-excel, table, exportação

Gostaria de saber se é possível criar uma função em PHP e/ou Javascript que permita exportar o conteúdo de uma tabela em HTML (table dentro de um div) direto pra um arquivo de Excel.

Estou tentando aproveitar uma função criada do site de um cliente meu, mas não deu muito certo. Então acho que preciso fazer algo de novo.

Pensei em algo assim: tendo uma table com o id = 'tableOne' e tendo na minha página um botão com id = 'testExcel'. Quando clicar nesse botão, vai na minha função em javascript:

```
$('#testExcel').click(function(){
    var conteudo_div = $('#tableOne').text();
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        data: ({
            conteudo_div: $('#tableOne').text()
        }),
        url: '[:raiz]cadAdmin/testExcel',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            alert(conteudo_div);
        }
    })
});
```

E depois a função testExcel da URL fica num arquivo de Controller da minha página:

```
public function testExcel(){
    $nome_arquivo = "Listagem de Investidores";
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$nome_arquivo.xls");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");

    $html = $_REQUEST['conteudo_div'];
    echo $html;
}
```

Só que, por enquanto, não funcionou. Alguma ideia?

Comment: Boa pergunta...

Answer (score 1):

Tente:

```
public function testExcel(){
    $nome_arquivo = "Listagem de Investidores";
    header("Content-type: text/txt");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$nome_arquivo.xls");
   header("Pragma: no-cache");

    $html = $_REQUEST['conteudo_div'];
    echo $html;
}
```

E ao invés de usar um ajax, use um window.open ou um form.submit no lugar, aí ele tentará abrir o link como um arquivo comum e usará a associação do arquivo do windows para abri-lo.

Não se esqueça de usar a função header antes de ecoar qualquer outra informação no arquivo, ou use html puro para definir estes cabeçalhos

O melhor mesmo é você usar o seguinte:

```
<form target="_blank" action="[:raiz]cadAdmin/testExcel" id="form_excel">
  <input type="hidden" name="conteudo_div" id="conteudo_div">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#testExcel').click(function(){
    $("#conteudo_div").val($('#tableOne').text());
    $("#form_excel").submit();
});
```

Faço algo parecido mas com vbscript.

Comment: Como que eu usou window.open nesse caso?

Comment: O window.open funcionaria se a tabela que vc quiser enviar for pequena, pois vc precisaria passar ela com
    window.open("[:raiz]cadAdmin/testExcel?conteudo_div=" + $('#tableOne').text()
Que possui uma limitação de tamanho de campo

Comment: Tente usar como parecido acima, use uma form que não exibe nada e só sirva para enviar estes dados